# Finding the equivalence class of this relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I am having this relation:

$$ A=\mathcal P(\mathbb  {N}  
\diagdown
0) ,  $$

```
                             A~B :<=>  min A = min B
```

I haved already proved, that it is a equivalence relation. Now I have to find an equivalence class for this relation. I am knowing the definition of an equivalence class 
$$[x] := y \in A|\ xRy $$

---

**What is the amount of the equivalence classes of this relation?**

Comment: I assume you mean $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ in the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ containing $1$ are equivalent. So the equivalence class for $1$ is
$$[1] = \{ \ \{ 1 \} \cup A \  \ |  \ \ A \in  \mathcal P(\{n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ n > 1 \}) \ \}$$

Hence in general...

Comment: So there is equivalence class for 2, for 3 and so on?   How can I write this down in a correct way?

Comment: Yes. Any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ containing $2$ but not $1$. You can model an explicit expression for $[2]$ on the one above. Similarly for $3, 4, ...$

Comment: Great explanation thanks. Is there a way to write this down or should I use "..." ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\begin{align}f\colon \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus\{\emptyset\}&\to \mathbb N\\S&\mapsto \min S\end{align} $$
is onto and for each $n\in\mathbb N$, the preimage $f^{-1}(n)$ is an equivalence class.